# OpenCV 2.4.7 Mat::convertTo() 32-bit to 16-bit truncate

Tags: opencv, matrix

I've noticed that using convertTo to convert a matrix from 32-bit to 16-bit "rounds" number to the upper boud. So, values bigger than 0x0000FFFF in the source matrix will be set as 0xFFFF in the destination matrix.

What I want for my application is instead to mask the values, setting in the destination just the 2 LSB of the values.

Here is an example:

```
Mat mat32;
Mat mat16;

mat32 = Mat(2,2,CV_32SC1);

for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
  for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    mat32.at<unsigned int>(cv::Point(x,y)) = 0x0000FFFE + (y*2+x);

mat32.convertTo(mat16, CV_16UC1);
```

The matrixes have these values:

```
32 bits matrix:
0000FFFE        0000FFFF
00010000        00010001

16 bits matrix:
0000FFFE        0000FFFF
0000FFFF        0000FFFF
```

In the second row of 16-bit matrix I want to have

```
00000000  00000001
```

I can do this by scanning the source matrix value-by-value and masking the values, but the performances are low.

Is there an OpenCV function that does this?

Thanks to everyone!

MIX

Comment: The root cause of your problem is that OpenCV applies cv::saturate_cast in the method cv::Mat::convertTo(). This is explicitly stated in the doc.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done, but this requires a somewhat dirty trick, so it is up to you to use this approach or not. So this is how it can be done:

For this example lets create 1000x1000 32-bit matrix and set all its values to 65541 (=256*256+5). So after the conversion we expect to have a matrix filled with fives.

```
Mat M1(1000, 1000, CV_32S, Scalar(65541));
```

And here is the trick:

```
Mat M2(1000, 1000, CV_16SC2, M1.data);
```

We created matrix M2 over the same memory buffer as M1, but M2 'think' that this is a buffer of 2-channel 16-bit image. Now the last thing to do is to copy the channel you need to the place you need. This can be done by split() or mixChannels() functions. For example:

```
Mat M3(1000, 1000, CV_16S);
int fromto[] = {0,0};
Mat inpu[] = {M2}, outpu[] = {M3};
mixChannels(inpu, 1, outpu, 1, fromto, 1);
cout << M3.at<short>(10,10) << endl;
```

Ye I know that the format of mixChannels looks weird and makes the code even less readable, but it works... If you prefer split() function:

```
vector<Mat> v;
split(M2,v);
cout << v[0].at<short>(10,10) << " " << v[1].at<short>(10,10) << endl;
```

Comment: I am not sure what did you mean by your comment. In case you meant that explanation is not clear I can try to rephrase it.

Comment: No, it's ok. It's just that is quite far from my usual approach, so I have (had) to read it many time to understand what's going on.

Comment: Nice approach, but is this endianness invariant? Will this produce the same result on a little or big endian machine?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OpenCV function (that I know of) which does the conversion like you want, so either you code it yourself or like you said you go through a masking step first to remove the 16 high bits.

The mask can be applied using the `bitwise_and` in C++ or `cvAndS` in C. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and).

You could also have made your hand-written code more efficient. In general, you should avoid OpenCV pixel accessors in loops because they have bad performance. I don't have an OpenCV install at hand so this could be slighlty off -- the idea is to use the `data` field directly, and `step` which is the number of bytes per row:

```
for(int y = 0; y < mat32.height; ++) {
  int* row = (int*)( (char*)mat32.data + y * mat32.step);
  for(int x = 0; x < mat32.step/ 4)
    row[x] &= 0xffff;
```

Then, once the mask is applied, all values fit in 16 bits, and `convertTo` will just truncate the 16 upper bits.

The other solution is to code the conversion by hand:

```
mat16.resize( mat32.size() );
for(int y = 0; y < mat32.height; ++) {
  const int* row32 = (const int*)( (char*)mat32.data + y * mat32.step);
  short*     row16 = (short*)    ( (char*)mat16.data + y * mat16.step);
  for(int x = 0; x < mat32.step/ 4)
    row16[x] = short(row32[x]);
```

Comment: Ok, no build-in functions for me... I've already created the conversion function. Using `data` field seems a little more efficent (while less readable). I didn't use it since I couldn't find the `widthStep` parameter in Mat class, like in IplImage (class that I used so far with OpenCV 1.x); than I noticed the `step` parameter. Dumb me!

Comment: Indeed, in the `Mat` class, it is called `step`, I'll correct my answer.